# VBA IsNull Handling

Tags: vba

Hi I am very new to vba and here I am trying to get records printed on an Excel worksheet.

This is my code:

```
While Not ActualList.EOF
    Actual = ActualList("Actual")
    If IsNull(Actual) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "0.00"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        Debug.Print Actual
        ActiveCell.Value = Actual
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
    ActualList.MoveNext
Wend
```

The ActualList record set has 4 items and includes null values.

To be more precise it has these items: 5960,NULL,NULL,NULL

I need to print those values, but what I get is 0,0,0,0

Please help

Comment: This can only work if Actual is a `Variant`. `Variant` is the only variable type that can be Null.

Comment: yes actual is variant,Still it happens

Comment: What is `ActualList`? A DAO/ADO recordset? Please show your full code including the variable declarations and initializations.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA there are several different types of nothing.

- Empty - `IsEmpty(v)` - `VT_EMPTY`
- Null - `IsNull(v)` - `VT_NULL`
- Nothing - `v Is Nothing` - `VT_UNKNOWN` or `VT_DISPATCH`
- Missing - `IsMissing(v)` - `VT_ERROR` with a specific error code
- Null String
- Empty String
- Various kinds of zero. (Single, Double, Short, Long, Byte, Decimal, Currency etc)

It is also possible that what you have is a string which is literally `"NULL"`

What you should do is put a breakpoint on that line and inspect the variable values.